# maximum call stack exceeded input click change

Tags: jquery, input, onclick, radio-button, click

I'm trying to trigger an input to become selected when its parent is clicked on. I'm having trouble with the input actually being "clicked", so I have called it to be clicked in the change function. However, when its being "clicked" in the change function, I have a maximum call stack exceeded. Please note that when I try to just change() the prop without actually clicking on it, it either wont click or it disables my active class functionality.

```
    init: function() {

          $('input:radio').on("change", function () {
              console.log($(this), 'clickeddd input')
              $(this).click();
          });

          $('[data-membership-check]').on('click', function() {

            var btnBox = $('[data-membership-type]');

            // if already active, remove on second click
              if ( $(this).hasClass('active') ) {
                $(this).removeClass('active');

                // uncheck hidden radio on deselect
                $(this).children('input:radio').prop('checked', false).change();

            // remove active class(es) and toggle active on
              } else {
                $('[data-membership-check]').removeClass('active');
                btnBox.removeClass('active');
                $(this).toggleClass('active');

                //check hidden radio button
                $(this).children('input:radio').prop('checked', true).change();
              }

            // toggle nearest container active class
            $(this).closest(btnBox).toggleClass('active');

        });
    }




          <div class="member-signup-choices">
            <div class="input-membership-type" data-membership-type>
              <label class="membership-type-title">
                Professional
              </label>
              <div class="membership-type-select">
                <span class="membership-input-icon membership-input-check" data-membership-check>
                  <input required="required" type="radio" id="edit-submitted-membership-type-1" name="submitted[membership_type]" value="4" class="form-radio">
                  <svg role="img">
                    <use xlink:href="../../assets/images/icons/icon-map.svg#icon-check">
                    </use>
                  </svg>
                </span>
                <!-- modal btn -->
                <a href="#international-modal" class="membership-input-icon membership-input-help" data-magnific-modal>
                  <svg role="img">
                    <use xlink:href="../../assets/images/icons/icon-map.svg#icon-help">
                    </use>
                  </svg>
                </a>
                <!-- /modal btn -->
              </div>
            </div>
            <div class="input-membership-type" data-membership-type>
              <label class="membership-type-title">
                Associate
              </label>
              <div class="membership-type-select">
                <span class="membership-input-icon membership-input-check" data-membership-check>
                  <input required="required" type="radio" id="edit-submitted-membership-type-2" name="submitted[membership_type]" value="4" class="form-radio">
                  <svg role="img">
                    <use xlink:href="../../assets/images/icons/icon-map.svg#icon-check">
                    </use>
                  </svg>
                </span>
                <!-- modal btn -->
                <a href="#international-modal" class="membership-input-icon membership-input-help" data-magnific-modal>
                  <svg role="img">
                    <use xlink:href="../../assets/images/icons/icon-map.svg#icon-help">
                    </use>
                  </svg>
                </a>
                <!-- /modal btn -->
              </div>
            </div>
            <div class="input-membership-type form-item-submitted-membership-type" data-membership-type>
              <!-- <input required="required" type="radio" id="edit-submitted-membership-type-3" name="submitted[membership_type]" value="3" class="form-radio">   -->
              <label class="membership-type-title">
                Student
              </label>
              <div class="membership-type-select">
                <span class="membership-input-icon membership-input-check" data-membership-check>
                  <input required="required" type="radio" id="edit-submitted-membership-type-3" name="submitted[membership_type]" value="4" class="form-radio">
                  <svg role="img">
                    <use xlink:href="../../assets/images/icons/icon-map.svg#icon-check">
                    </use>
                  </svg>
                </span>
                <!-- modal btn -->
                <a href="#international-modal" class="membership-input-icon membership-input-help" data-magnific-modal>
                  <svg role="img">
                    <use xlink:href="../../assets/images/icons/icon-map.svg#icon-help">
                    </use>
                  </svg>
                </a>
                <!-- /modal btn -->
              </div>
            </div>
            <div class="input-membership-type form-item-submitted-membership-type" data-membership-type>
              <label class="membership-type-title">
                Affiliate
              </label>
              <div class="membership-type-select">
                <span class="membership-input-icon membership-input-check" data-membership-check>
                  <input required="required" type="radio" id="edit-submitted-membership-type-4" name="submitted[membership_type]" value="4" class="form-radio">
                  <svg role="img">
                    <use xlink:href="../../assets/images/icons/icon-map.svg#icon-check">
                    </use>
                  </svg>
                </span>
                <!-- modal btn -->
                <a href="#international-modal" class="membership-input-icon membership-input-help" data-magnific-modal>
                  <svg role="img">
                    <use xlink:href="../../assets/images/icons/icon-map.svg#icon-help">
                    </use>
                  </svg>
                </a>
                <!-- /modal btn -->
              </div>
            </div>
            <div class="input-membership-type form-item-submitted-membership-type" data-membership-type>
              <label class="membership-type-title">
                International
              </label>
              <div class="membership-type-select">
                <span class="membership-input-icon membership-input-check" data-membership-check>
                  <input required="required" type="radio" id="edit-submitted-membership-type-5" name="submitted[membership_type]" value="4" class="form-radio">
                  <svg role="img">
                    <use xlink:href="../../assets/images/icons/icon-map.svg#icon-check">
                    </use>
                  </svg>
                </span>
                <!-- modal btn -->
                <a href="#international-modal" class="membership-input-icon membership-input-help" data-magnific-modal>
                  <svg role="img">
                    <use xlink:href="../../assets/images/icons/icon-map.svg#icon-help">
                    </use>
                  </svg>
                </a>
                <!-- /modal btn -->
              </div>
            </div>
            <div class="input-membership-type form-item-submitted-membership-type" data-membership-type>
              <label class="membership-type-title">
                Industry
              </label>
              <div class="membership-type-select">
                <span class="membership-input-icon membership-input-check" data-membership-check>
                  <input required="required" type="radio" id="edit-submitted-membership-type-4" name="submitted[membership_type]" value="4" class="form-radio">
                  <svg role="img">
                    <use xlink:href="../../assets/images/icons/icon-map.svg#icon-check">
                    </use>
                  </svg>
                </span>
                <!-- modal btn -->
                <a href="#international-modal" class="membership-input-icon membership-input-help" data-magnific-modal>
                  <svg role="img">
                    <use xlink:href="../../assets/images/icons/icon-map.svg#icon-help">
                    </use>
                  </svg>
                </a>
                <!-- /modal btn -->
              </div>
            </div>
          </div>
```

Answer (score 0):

The problem is in these 2 lines:

```
$(this).children('input:radio').prop('checked', false).change();
$(this).children('input:radio').prop('checked', true).change();
```

`.change()` triggers the `change` event on the radio buttons. The `prop()` method handles changing their `checked` property, so calling this method is unnecessary. It's a problem because `.change()` triggers the `change` event handler declared at the top, which then triggers another `click` event on the input, and this process continues in an infinite loop. There should be no need to call `.change()` on the radio inputs after changing their `checked` property. Try removing that step from those 2 lines:

```
$(this).children('input:radio').prop('checked', false);
$(this).children('input:radio').prop('checked', true);
```

Answer (score 0):

remove 'input:radio' change event and do write required jquery code inside 'data-membership-check' click event.